# MySql Count the same value

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have this table. My task is this : **Count the students having the same first name.**

I want it to show me just the firstname and then how many times firstname is found:

like this:  `bob | 2`

```
id      firstN   lastN      group  grade    tax     gender  year    university 
9       Alyson   Hanniga    112     1       0       female  1       UTC
5       Barney   Stinson    111     4       0       male    1       UBB
8       Bob      Saget      111     6       900     male    3       UBB
14      Bob      Bob        112     10      250     male    1       UBB
11      Cobie    Smulder    111     9       200     female  1       Dragos Voda
7       David    Henrie     112     9       0       male    1       Dragos Voda
12      Jason    Segel      112     10      150     male    1       UTC
13      Josh     Radnor     112     7       0       male    2       Dragos Voda
4       Lily     Aldrin     112     5       400     female  1       UBB
6       Lyndsy   Fonseca    113     10      0       female  3       UTC
2       Marshal  Eriksen    112     10      100     male    2       UTC
10      Neil     Patrick    112     7       0       male    3       Dragos Voda
1       Robin    Scherba    111     10      0       female  1       UBB
3       Ted      Mosby      112     8       0       male    2       UBB
```

Comment: pff.. well this is stupid. How can i edit this and copy/paste a table.. It wont let me post images :(

Comment: To do that you need to gain some reputation on this site. Read: [*FAQ for Stack Exchange sites*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: select firstName, count(*) from student  group by firstName having count(*) > 1;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is query for

```
select FirstName,count(*) from tblStudent group by FirstName
```